# Locate a tab item from list of tabs that is selected using pywinauto

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am trying to get hold of a tab item that is selected using pywinauto. I am not able to get the correct property which is best to identify that element.

here's a sample code i am using to get to the list of tab items.

here's a list of

```
app = Application(backend = "uia").start(app_path, timeout=10)

dlg = app.WindowTitle

tabs = dlg.child_window(title = "somet_title", control_type = "Tab").children()

for tab in tabs:
    print(i.is_enabled())

app.kill()
```

i don't think is_enabled() is correct because it results in true for all tabs. but only one of them is selected.

Please tell me how i should proceed here? Also let me know what else do i need to share?